# How to drag listview item into other tab?

Tags: android

I have a Tab activity that has 3 tabs. Each tab is a ListView. I wanted to drag any list item from tab1 and drop it into tab2. I tried a lot but couldn't find any such example. If anyone has an idea please let me know.

Comment: I have some Idea, but I can't test now. If you don't have any solution about this, I'll try to solve it in this weekend.

Comment: yes I don't have any solution. If you have any example link please provide it to me. thanks

Comment: hello, I found this tutorial. :)
http://android-er.blogspot.kr/2012/04/drag-and-drop-to-copy-items-between.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can solve it by using support v4 make the tab2 extends fragment-activity and wish item of list extends fragment and than u call those fragment and open them in the tab2 wish this can help u